# wordpress: display current tag-id

Tags: wordpress, tags

With

```
$tag = single_tag_title('', false);
```

I can get the name of the currently chosen tag. Right?

But how can I get also the ID of the chosen tag? "single_tag_id" does not exist. And afterwards I would like to show only posts with the tag-id.

```
$args = array(
            'tag' => 'ID HERE?',
        );
```

But I can not put a number into 'tag'. How can I filter with tag-id and not do it by name?

Comment: Been looking for an answer for hours now, i wanted to get the tag name and your question solved mine haha! Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do the following

```
     $tag_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
```

And then

```
    $args = array(
        'tag' => $tag_id,
    );
```